# Import one GIT repository into multiple repositories using file type filter

Tags: git, svn, filter, migration, repository

So I've been tasked with merging our current SVN repositories from SVN to GIT using  my VSTS account as the remote repository location. I understand how to convert SVN to GIT locally and import them into the remote repository however there is a problem.

Is there a way (when importing from a local repository to the remote) to filter out and send file types to different repositories at the same time?

I.e., I have one repository and through file type sorting I'm able to send 3 different types of documents to 3 separate repositories.

Sorry if that is a bit confusing but I'm just trying to see if there is any other way of doing this than manual.

Comment: Are you saying that with a repo containing files `a.js`, `utils/b.js`, `c.java`, `utils/d.java`, and `README.txt`, you want three output repos containing the files [`a.js`, `utils/b.js`], [`c.java`, `utils/d.java`], and [`README.txt`]? That is, there are no constraints about which folder the files of different types may be in, and every different file type in the project should get its own repo?

Comment: Tools that might help: [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/esr/reposurgeon/)

Comment: no, currently we're using SVN and the programming we use (in house) requires we have .xsl, .csv and .app files. Bare minimum I'd just like to split the .xsl and .app files when I import.

Comment: If you have a repo for .xsl files and a repo for .app files, where do the other files go? Are they duplicated in each repo, or missing from both repos?